# What the correct way to configure gradle in intellij for libgdx?

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx

When I try to build libgdx project I get this error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.
>   /> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

what could be the problem?